# How to remove the page number from the end of a reference

Tags: bibtex, back-referencing

I am using `aaai`(`aaai.bst`) as `bibliographystyle`. The problem is every reference is tailing a page number where it appears in my thesis. I am wondering how to remove the page number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the template you used. (More information was posted to [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum/) in [How to remove the page number from the end of a reference](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=26578) including template and `bst` file).

My statement there is, that `\usepackage{backref}` (or a `backref` or a `pagebackref` option) has been used and should be removed.

Update: in the thread it actually turned out that the cause was die Option `pagebackref` to `hyperref`.